# Refresh Angular 4 Table

Tags: angular, typescript

Im having trouble with my angular 4 application. I am taking a user input and appending it to an array, which holds the data for the table. I can see that the input is being pushed into the array, but the Table itself isn't updating. I have tried using changeDetection and true,false conditions, but was unfortunately unsucessful. Is there another way to update the table with the pushed data? My code is below, including the table html,ts docs, and input ts doc. Many thanks!

Input-form.component.ts

```
export class InputFormComponent implements OnInit {
  subjectItems: Array<string> = [];
  subjectNumber = 0;

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addSubjectToTable (position2, subjectNameItem2, totalTimeStudy2) {
    SubjectTableDATA.push({
      position: position2, subjectNameItem: subjectNameItem2,
      totalTimeStudy: totalTimeStudy2
    });
    console.log('subejcttable called');
    console.log(SubjectTableDATA);
    reloadTable();
    console.log('reloadTable func called');
  }
  addSubject(subjectName, timeStudy) {
    console.log('Called function');
    if (subjectName && timeStudy) {
      console.log('All fields inputted, adding...');
      this.subjectItems.push(subjectName, timeStudy);
      this.subjectNumber += 1;
      console.log(this.subjectItems);
      this.addSubjectToTable(this.subjectNumber, subjectName, timeStudy);
    }
  }

}
```

table.component.ts

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'subjectNameItem', 'totalTimeStudy'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SubjectTable>(SubjectTableDATA);

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit () {}
}
export interface SubjectTable {
  position: number;
  subjectNameItem: string;
  totalTimeStudy: string;

}
export var SubjectTableDATA: SubjectTable[] = [
  {position: 1, subjectNameItem: 'math', totalTimeStudy: '9 hours'}
];

export function reloadTable () {
  console.log('reloading table');
}
```

table.component.html

```
<div class="TableForInputtedSubjects">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID: </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let SubjectTable"> {{SubjectTable.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="subjectNameItem">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Subject Name: </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let SubjectTable"> {{SubjectTable.subjectNameItem}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="totalTimeStudy">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total Study Time: </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let SubjectTable"> {{SubjectTable.totalTimeStudy}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see you are updating `SubjectTableDATA` in `Input-form.component`, but it's unclear how it propagates the change to `table.component.ts`. Even if you somehow propagated the change, you are not updating `table.component`'s `datasource`, it's initialized once, and never gets updated/reassigned. And the `reloadTable` method doesn't do anything excepting logging to the console.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I imported the SubjectTableDATA from the TableComponent, into the input form component, as its the place where new input comes from the input forms. Wouldn't that mean that its pushing into the SubjectTableDATA of TableComponent? Is there no possibility to initialize dataSource more than once? I left reloadTable with a console log since I don't yet know how to update the table, the purpose of it is to reinitialize the Table.

Comment: No, that's not how it works, if you want to share a variable across multiple components you should either pass it as an [Input](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/) parameter from the parent to the child component or use a shared data service.